# How to put & (ampersand) intead of and sign in bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, abbrvnat.bst

I am writing the bib tex I want to put `&` instead of `and` between two authors.

```
  @article{link:cac,
 title   = {A comparison between public key authority and 
            certification authority for distribution of 
            public key},
 author  = {Agarwal, Gaurav and Singh, Saurabh},
 journal = {International Journal of Computer Science 
            and Information Technologies},
 volume  = {1},
 number  = {5},
 pages   = {332--336},
 year    = {2010}
}
```

Output is as follow:

```
G. Agarwal and S. Singh, “A comparison between public key authority and
certification authority for distribution of public key”. International Journal
of Computer Science and Information Technologies, 1(5):332–336, 2010
```

When I change this code as below. It changed the author name.

```
@article{link:cac,
     title   = {A comparison between public key authority and 
                certification authority for distribution of 
                public key},
     author  = {Agarwal, Gaurav {\&} Singh, Saurabh},
     journal = {International Journal of Computer Science 
                and Information Technologies},
     volume  = {1},
     number  = {5},
     pages   = {332--336},
     year    = {2010}
    }
```

The output it shows as follow:

```
  S. Agarwal, Gaurav & Singh, “A comparison between public key authority and
    certification authority for distribution of public key”. International Journal of Computer Science and Information Technologies, 1(5):332–336, 2010.
```

What can i do for this. Please help me to make my bib item.
**Note:** I use  abbrvnat style.

Comment: Leave the "and" in your source but change the "format.names" part of the style file.

Comment: Your question is tagged as `biblatex` and as `bibtex`, which one are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following does the trick (if you're using `biblatex`):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-and.bib}

\renewcommand*\finalnamedelim{\addspace\&\space}

\begin{document}
\cite{link:cac}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand*\finalnamedelim{\addspace\&\space}` would be a bit more `biblatex`-y, though. The 'I use abbrvnat style' makes it quite probable that the question was incorrectly tagged and that the OP does not use `biblatex`, but BibTeX.

Comment: @moewe but I don't know how to do this with BibTeX :)